# How to enable local network users access my XAMPP sites hosted on a windows?

Tags: xampp, localhost, server, local-network

I need to conduct a online quiz in LAN in my college....I have created online quiz website using PHP in XAMPP server...I need to give access of the site to all the clients connected in the LAN....Please help me to perform this successfuly...Thank u in advance

Platform: Windows

Server: XAMPP

Upto now I have no idea regarding the access of websites in LAN.So i cannot try it on my own....I used google for getting answer to my question but it was not clear regarding my question.
I wonder if there is any specific steps that I can walk through to make it really work?

Thank You All